# How to use result of function as link for button

Tags: php, wordpress, button, hyperlink, elementor

I added a function to my functions.php that calculates what my latest post is and returns the link to that post. Now I want to use the result of this function when I press my button. So basically I have a button that's called: 'latest blog' and that should link to the latest blog when it's clicked on.

The function itself is:

```
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'     => 1,
        'offset'          => 0,
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'DESC',
        'post_status'     => 'publish' );
    $sorted_posts = get_posts( $args );
    $permalink = get_permalink($sorted_posts[0]->ID);
    return $permalink;
}
```

and I have a button on my home page which currently has a hardcoded link: https://www.markt54.be/

I'm configuring everything in elementor pro in my wordpress site. Has someone any advice?

Answer (score 0):

while adding a blog/post insert its SR/Index number + URL in DB,use auto increment columns

while loading data check which is the latest record in DB and use Last ID' URL in hyperlink like

```html
//some PHP Mysql Code
storing the value of the latest record 's URL in Variable

$url = $row["url"];;
//some PHP Mysql Code

<a href="www.websitename.com/<?php echo $url; ?>">Button</a>
```

Comment: seems to be a quite different setup then the one I use currently and I don't know how to implement this in wordpress...